SharePoint 2016 Add-In CommandUIHandler EnabledScript is not working for Custom Ribbon Button
I'm working with SharePoint 2016 on-premise. I created an Add-In and I want to add a custom ribbon button to a document library. I need this button to be enabled only when exactly one item is selected. Here is the XML I have used for the custom action:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="33b99e86-844e-40e6-93da-3b31f1314310.RibbonCustomAction1"
                RegistrationType="List"
                RegistrationId="101"
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
                Sequence="10001"
                Title="Invoke 'RibbonCustomAction1' action">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.RibbonCustomAction1Button"
                  Alt="My Custom Ribbon Button"
                  Sequence="100"
                  Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
                  LabelText="My Custom Ribbon Button"
                  TemplateAlias="o1"
                  Image32by32="_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png"
                  Image16by16="_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
                          CommandAction="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}&amp;SPListId={SelectedListId}&amp;SPSource={Source}&amp;SPListURLDir={ListUrlDir}"
                          EnabledScript="javascript:SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems().length === 1;" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>

However, this approach does not seem to work as expected. The button does not enable or disable based on the number of selected items.
Interestingly, if I create a separate empty project and add this exact XML into an empty elements.xml, the newly created button works as expected.
I have the latest CU installed. I've also tried addressing the custom JS function from \Web Server Extensions\16\. Even EnabledScript="javascript:return false;" does not work. I've seen many solutions here, but none of them work.
I am wondering why the EnabledScript does not work for the button inside the custom ribbon action in the SharePoint Add-In.
